# Is There are a Way to Write just Next/Prev Post Link on Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, pagination

I want to customize next/previous posts links **pagination** to this structure:

```
<!--PAGINATION-->
<a href="#prev_post_link#" id="pagePrev" class="button"><span>&laquo; Önceki</span></a>
<a href="#next_post_link#" id="pageNext" class="button"><span>Sonraki &raquo;</span></a>
<!--/PAGINATION-->
```

So i want to echo just next/previous post link to `#prev_post_link#` and `#next_post_link#` for building custom next/prev **pagination**.

Comment: &laquo;? That's a quote mark, please don't use it as UTF-8 art! (This is what the future has brought us, who needs ASCII art any more?)

Comment: I understand you. But i will use it for now. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem with JS:

```
    $('div#pagination').ready(function() { 
    if ( $('div#pagination a').length == 1 && $('div#pagination a').text() == 'Sonraki »' ) { 
        $('div#pagination a').before('<a href="javascript:;" class="button"><span>« Önceki</span></a>');
        $('div#pagination a:first').css('opacity', '.5');
    }
    if ( $('div#pagination a').length == 1 && $('div#pagination a').text() == '« Önceki' ) { 
        $('div#pagination a').after('<a href="javascript:;" class="button"><span>Sonraki »</span></a>');
        $('div#pagination a:last').css('opacity', '.5');
    }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/previous_post has some examples. I use the following in one of my sites.

```
<?php previous_post_link('<p id="next-link">%link</p>', 'Next Post, TRUE); ?>
```

The link is denoted by %link. You can add your class or wrapper around it. I do not think you can style the  tag directly without core hack to Wordpress.

Any kind of styling you require can be achieved using the wrapping ID. In my example, the  can be styled in css using

```
p#next-link a {}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This function is deprecated. Also that will not solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use get_adjacent_post() for this.

Example:

```
$prev_post = get_adjacent_post(false, '', true);  
$prev_post_link = ($prev_post ? get_permalink( $prev_post->ID ) : "");
$next_post = get_adjacent_post(false, '', false);  
$next_post_link = ($next_post ? get_permalink( $next_post->ID ) : "");
```

Comment: Can you explain it much more?

Comment: But i don't working on single.php. I'm working on "custom page template.":(http://pastie.org/private/ynhgmlii1nssswgotyaa5w)

Answer (score 0):

There's a way to do what you're looking for in your theme template - but I've also had good luck w/ this plugin - http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-pagenavi/

If your still not having any luck after that, comment back & I'll post the code.

Comment: Also, take a look at this for documentation - http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/previous_posts_link &
http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/next_posts_link

Hopefully that will spur some ideas for you